# How to select a dynamic radio button in Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px;">
    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 impl-slick-cell-radiosel">
    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">AAA</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2" title="">9999</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">---</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4">17 Apr, 2013</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l5 r5">C02312</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:25px;">
    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 impl-slick-cell-radiosel" title="">
    <input type="radio"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1" title="">BBB</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2" title="">8950</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">---</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4">04 Apr, 2013</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l5 r5">C3285</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:50px;">
    <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 impl-slick-cell-radiosel">
    <div class="slick-cell l1 r1" title="">CCC</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l2 r2" title="">7856</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l3 r3">CC</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l4 r4">16 Apr, 2001</div>
    <div class="slick-cell l5 r5">C958</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:75px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:100px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:125px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:150px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:175px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:200px;">
```

I am trying to select "slick-cell l2 r2" and "9999", "slick-cell l2 r2" and "8950" from a list of  buttons, but can't find a way to select them.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Comment: try `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ui-widget-content.slick-row.even div.slick-cell.l2.r2').click()`

Comment: I have tried but failed, Please see below error 
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ui-widget-content.s??lick-row.even div.slick-cell.l2.r2').click()
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 450, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 784, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']

Comment: web_element = driver.find_element(class: 'l2 r2'), try once

Comment: and is this page dynamic? can you tell how is it dynamic?